# Can I have multiple sections in a php file and call them individually to another php file depending up on requirements

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a php page with html codes. I managed to call one php file to another php file. But now I am trying to have one php file with multiple sections with different kind of inputs and have them called separately as and when needed. I'm a new bee to php so please apologize if my question sounds silly.
In my webpage, I have `country.php` file with

```
<option value="AUS">Australia</option>
<option value="IND">India</option>
<option value="US">United State</option>
```

In my second page where I have form controls, I am using a following code to call above php file which works fine.

```
Country <select> <?php include "country.php"; ?> </select>
```

But this forces me to create separate files for each drop down items. 
Is it possible to have one file like `selections.php` and call the items separately to the from controls in another page ?

```
selection.php
<!-- Countries -->

        <option value="AUS">Australia</option>
        <option value="IND">India</option>
        <option value="US">United State</option>


<!-- Designation -->


        <option value="mgr">Manager</option>
        <option value="amgr">Asst. Manager</option>
        <option value="supr">Supervisor</option>


<!-- Departments -->

        <option value="it">IT</option>
        <option value="finance">Finance</option>
        <option value="oadmin">Office Admin</option>



form.php

Country <select> ??? </select>
Designation <select> ??? </select>
Department <select> ??? </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
Country <select> <?php $type = 'country'; include "selection.php"; ?> </select>
```

And call selection.php with condition.

```
<?php if($type == 'country'): ?>
<!-- Countries -->

    <option value="AUS">Australia</option>
    <option value="IND">India</option>
    <option value="US">United State</option>

<?php elsif($type == 'designation'): ?>
<!-- Designation -->


    <option value="mgr">Manager</option>
    <option value="amgr">Asst. Manager</option>
    <option value="supr">Supervisor</option>

<?php elseif($type == 'department'): ?>
<!-- Departments -->

    <option value="it">IT</option>
    <option value="finance">Finance</option>
    <option value="oadmin">Office Admin</option>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Off course you can use **switch** or whatever you prefer. Also one personal suggestions , try some frameworks like laravel, Yii.

Answer (score 1):

You can have functions such as countries(), designation() etc outputting individual HTML as required. So your selection.php becomes

```php
<?php
    function countries() {
?>
        <option value="AUS">Australia</option>
        <option value="IND">India</option>
        <option value="US">United State</option>
<?php
    }
?>
```

And so on, so forth defining different functions.

Also, if this gets too complicated have a look at using a template engine such as [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org)

Answer (score 1):

**index.php**:
Include your file like this:

```
$menu = "countries";
include("selections.php");
```

**selections.php**:

```
$types = [];

$types["countries"] = [];
$types["countries"]["aus"] = "Australia";
$types["countries"]["ind"] = "India";
$types["countries"]["us"] = "United States";

$types["designation"] = [];
$types["designation"]["mgr"] = "Manager";
$types["designation"]["amgr"] = "Asst. Manager";
$types["designation"]["supr"] = "Supervisor";

if(isset($menu) && isset($types[$menu])){
echo "<select>";
foreach ($types[$menu] as $value=>$label){
    echo "<option name='$menu' value='$value'>$label</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
}else{
    echo "Error displaying dropdown menu.";
}
```

This way you can easily change (and add) menus and menu items just by changing (or adding) elements to the array `$types`.

If you have any questions, please ask.

I hope this helped,
Sebastian